# Referring to an attribute in an MDI application

Tags: python, attributes, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm just learning about tabbed views and MDI in PyQt. I'm confused how I would refer to a line-edit widget that is on one of the tabs. When I look at the object inspector I see:

```
MainWindow
  centralwidget
    mdiArea
     subwindow
      gridlayout
        wt1
```

I wish to refer to `wt1` in code. How do I do this?

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\218003107\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-  packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/218003107/callphreeqcInput.pyw", line 38, in <module>
    myapp=MyForm()
  File "C:/Users/218003107/callphreeqcInput.pyw", line 10, in __init__
    self.connect(self.ui.wt1,QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'),self.wtResult)
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'wt1'
```

My code looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from phreqMDI import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.connect(self.ui.wt1,QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'),self.wtResult)
        self.connect(self.ui.wt2,QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'),self.wtResult)
        self.connect(self.ui.wt3,QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'),self.wtResult)
        self.connect(self.ui.wt4,QtCore.SIGNAL('textChanged()'),self.wtResult)     

    def wtResult(self):
        if len(self.ui.wt1.text())!=0:
            a=float(self.ui.wt1.text())
        else:
            a=0
        if len(self.ui.wt2.text())!=0:
            b=float(self.ui.wt2.text())
        else:
            b=0
        if len(self.ui.wt3.text())!=0:
            c=float(self.ui.wt3.text())
        else:
            c=0
        if len(self.ui.wt4.text())!=0:
            c=float(self.ui.wt4.text())
        else:
            d=0                      
        sum=a+b+c+d
        self.ui.wt_total.setText(str(sum)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: You're mixing up two different methods of adding widgets from Qt Designer: multiple-inheritance and composition. You don't need to inherit from `Ui_MainWindow` - but fixing that won't fix the other problem. If you use the composition method, all the widgets from Qt Designer will become attributes of the `ui` object. However, I suspect that the real problem is that you haven't re-generated the `phreqMDI` module after making some changes (i.e. you need to run `pyuic` again).

Comment: Deleted UI_MainWindow as suggested. I also ran pyuic4 again. This time the program did not kick out an error. The main window opened but there were no widgets or tabs. All I could see is what looked like a main window with a grey MDI area. Note that I am able to see all the widgets and the two subwindows when I preview in Qt Designer. 

My applications has two subwindows and a lot of line edit and label widgets on one of the subwindows.


Any suggestions on why I am not seeing the subwindows or the widgets ?

Comment: Please add the designer ui file to your question, and I will try to see what's wrong.

Comment: What's the best way to add the file ? The .py version of the .ui is almost 500 lines long ? Is there a way to upload that I'm not seeing ? If I post the 500 lines in this add comment box, I get a message saying I've used too many characters.

Comment: You could use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link. And please post the `.ui` file, not the `.py` version.

Comment: Pastebin is pretty cool ! I think I did this correctly. If not, please let me know and I will correct it.

http://pastebin.com/q22K3Kq1

Comment: Please excuse me, I posted the .py file. I will post the .ui file shortly.

Comment: It's okay, I think I've found the problem - I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: OK, .ui is posted.

http://pastebin.com/7mruTPiZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `pyuic` does not automatically add the subwindows to the mdi-area. This seems like a bug to me, but I've never used mdi-areas myself, so maybe I'm missing something.

Anyway, you can fix the issue by adding the subwindows yourself, like this:

```
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
    self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_2)
```

See the [QMdiArea docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#addSubWindow) for more details.

**UPDATE**:

The reason why the signal connections don't work is because you are using the wrong signature. The is a very common mistake when using the [old-style method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html) of connecting signals, so I would advise switching to the [new-style method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), which would look like this:

```
    self.ui.wt1.editingFinished.connect(self.wtResult)
    self.ui.wt2.editingFinished.connect(self.wtResult)
    self.ui.wt3.editingFinished.connect(self.wtResult)
    self.ui.wt4.editingFinished.connect(self.wtResult)
```

Note that I have used the [editingFinished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal here, so that only complete entries are evaluated. If you used the `textChanged` signal, the `wtResult` method would try to evaluate intermediate entries (e.g. `"2."`), which would give errors.

You should probably consider [setting a validator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#setValidator) on your input fields so that only numeric values can be entered.

Comment: Wow, I would have never figured that out. Thanks so much !

I put these into __init__ after the call to setup. The GUI works but the text changed signal and associated call to wtResult does not. Is this a result of putting these two statements in the wrong place or just problems with my code ?

Comment: @user3720101. I have updated my answer to deal with the other issues. If you have further problems, please start a new question. (Also, if you found this answer useful, please mark it as accepted).